# Shift rows of a large matrix horizontally

Tags: r, matrix

I am looking for a way to shift the rows of a square matrix horizontally. Particularly, my question is for a case where the dimension of a matrix is very large, say 500*500 or 1000*1000, but I am giving a small example of 5*5 here to make it clear. Assume we have the following matrix:

```
 1    2    3    4    5
 6    7    8    9   10
11   12   13   14   15
16   17   18   19   20
21   22   23   24   25
```

I would like to shift the rows horizontally in which I get the following matrix and fill the empty cells with zero:

```
1    7   13   19   25
2    8   14   20    0
3    9   15    0    0
4   10    0    0    0
5    0    0    0    0
```

Writing code for a small matrix such as this is easy in `R`, but I am looking for very large matrices as I pointed out the above. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example suggests you want to create a new matrix whose jth *column* is the jth *row* of the original, shifted to the left j-1 places and padded with zeros on the right, as in this calculation with a 10,000 X 10,000 matrix:

```
n <- 1e4
a <- matrix(seq_len(n^2), n, byrow=TRUE)
system.time({
  b <- matrix(sapply(seq_len(nrow(a)), function(i) c(a[i,i:ncol(a)], rep(0, i-1))), n, n)
})
```

> ```
> user  system elapsed 
> 0.97    0.00    0.99
> ```

(That's using a single thread and reflects a typical run out of many test runs.) One second for a matrix with 100,000,000 entries isn't bad.  It's a big RAM hog though, so you might want to modify the code if the input is a sparse matrix so that it outputs a sparse matrix, too.

---

Reflecting on this, it occurred to me that avoiding the concatenation `c` and just copying in place should be faster, assuming one could initialize a matrix of zeros extremely quickly.  That turns out to the be the case (and the code is even simpler):

```
system.time({
  b <- matrix(0, nrow(a), ncol(a))
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(a))) b[1:(n+1-i), i] <- a[i, i:ncol(a)]
})
```

> ```
> user  system elapsed 
> 0.62    0.00    0.62
> ```

It's about 50% faster. Since the loop overhead will be relatively small and the body of the loop is (presumably) an optimized vector copy, it's unlikely an appreciably faster single-threaded solution exists.